# Can't get accessed to fields of instances in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

There have already been some documents in the events collection, however when I try to log out the field "eventId", it shows me "unfefined".
Following is  the code:

```
var EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
eventId: { type: Number, required: true,unique: true },
name: { type: String, required: true },
loc: { type: ObjectId },
quota: { type: Number }
});


var Event = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);

app.get('/test',function(req,res){   
        Event.find(function(err,result){
                if(err)
                        console.log("Not found");
            console.log("This is" + result.eventId);
            res.send(result);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  eventId: { type: Number, required: true,unique: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  loc: { type: ObjectId },
  quota: { type: Number }
});

var Event = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);

app.get('/test', async function(req,res){   
  const result = await Event.find();
  console.log("This is the result: " + result);
  res.send(result);
});
```

I think your problem is the callback is in the filter object position of the .find() method. The following may also work:

```
var EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  eventId: { type: Number, required: true,unique: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  loc: { type: ObjectId },
  quota: { type: Number }
});

var Event = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);

app.get('/test',function(req,res){   
  Event.find({}, function(err,result){
    if(err) console.log("Not found");
    console.log("This is" + result.eventId);
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried filling the filter by {} but nothing changed, actually res.send() works just fine, the response can be sent successfully.